# If setState doesnt return a Promise, why does await work in this case

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider example:

```
state = { x: false };

x = () => {
   this.setState({ x: true });
};

y = async () => {
   await this.x();
   console.log(this.state.x);
   ^^^^  // logs true if used with await, logs false if await removed
};

y();
```

Since setState is async, the state update should happen after `console.log`, so `false` should be logged. And so it does.

#### HOWEVER!

If I use an async func and AWAIT the `this.x()`, the `true` value is being logged. How? Why?

Playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-13fhfd?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Even if `this.setState` *did* return a promise, `x` doesn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then why does it work. And `this.setState` cant return a promise since it doesnt return a promise

Comment: in order to async await the method need to return a promise

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was about to say that, but I don't think it matters for the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okey so the await delays the execution a little bit thats why the state updates before logging

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on what is happening. Someone with more experience about the execution engine internals may have a more accurate answer, but I'm trying to think on a high level.

When we use the await keyword, it waits on a promise (if the expression is not a promise, then it is automatically wrapped around a `promise.resolve()`).

So here what is happening is that `x()` runs, and it calls `this.setState` which is async, so it goes into the event loop. Once that returns, the await keyword wraps that into another promise, which then goes into the event loop. setState is thus further ahead in the event loop, and hence gets executed first. Once that promise resolves, we move ahead to the console.log, and by then the value for state has changed.